# How to specify groups with colors in qqplot()?

Tags: r

I have created a qqplot (with quantiles of beta distribution) from a dataset including two groups. To visualize, which points belong to which group, I would like to color them. I have tried the following:

```
res <- beta.mle(data$values)  #estimate parameters of beta distribution
qqplot(qbeta(ppoints(500),res$param[1], res$param[2]),data$values, 
       col = data$group,
       ylab = "Quantiles of data",
       xlab = "Quantiles of Beta Distribution")
```

the result is shown here:
[image: the result is shown here]

I have seen solutions specifying a "col" vector for qqnorm, hover this seems to not work with qqplot, as simply half the points is colored in either color, regardless of group. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A simulated some data just to shown how to add color in `ggplot`

### Libraries

```
library(tidyverse)

# install.packages("Rfast")
```

### Data

```
#Simulating data from beta distribution 
x <- rbeta(n = 1000,shape1 = .5,shape2 = .5)

#Estimating parameters 

res <- Rfast::beta.mle(x)

data <-
  tibble(
    simulated_data = sort(x),
    quantile_data = qbeta(ppoints(length(x)),res$param[1], res$param[2])
  ) %>% 
  #Creating a group variable using quartiles
  mutate(group = cut(x = simulated_data,
                     quantile(simulated_data,seq(0,1,.25)),
                     include.lowest = T))
```

### Code

```
data %>% 
  # Adding group variable as color
  ggplot(aes( x = quantile_data, y = simulated_data, col = group))+
  geom_point()
```

#### Output

[image]

Comment: I am glad it helped you, if you could "close" the question, here is a tutorial for best practices: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0):

For those who are wondering, how to work with pre-defined groups, this is the code that worked for me:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(Rfast)
    
res <- beta.mle(x)
    
# make sure groups are not numerrical 
# (else color skale might turn out continuous)
    g <- plyr::mapvalues(g, c("1", "2"), c("Group1", "Group2"))
    
    data <-
      tibble(
        my_data = sort(x),
        quantile_data = qbeta(ppoints(length(x)),res$param[1], res$param[2]),
        group = g[order(x)]
      )
    
    data %>% 
      # Adding group variable as color
      ggplot(aes( x = quantile_data, y = my_data, col = group))+
      geom_point()
```

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u44Wx.png)